# Json serialization settings for specific controllers in .NET Core

Tags: json, .net-core, serialization, controller, json.net

I have to convert a project to .NET Core. In the source project there are 2 controllers with each 1 endpoint (method). Both methods return a list of Customer objects, which are returned to the caller deserialized in JSON format.
One of the controllers has a special attribute :

```
[SerializationConfiguration(typeof(CustomerSerializationSettings))]
```

SerializationConfiguration does below, so before sending the Json result to the caller the Json is changed via a formatter set in HttpControllerSettings :

```
public SerializationConfigurationAttribute(Type jsonSerializerType)
{
    JsonSerializerSettings = (ISerializationSettings)Activator.CreateInstance(jsonSerializerType);
}

public void Initialize(HttpControllerSettings controllerSettings, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor)
{
    controllerSettings.Formatters.Remove(controllerSettings.Formatters.JsonFormatter);

    var formatter = JsonSerializerSettings.SerializerSettings.ToFormatter();

    controllerSettings.Formatters.Insert(0, formatter);
}
```

CustomerSerializationSettings looks like this :

```
public class CustomerSerializationSettings : ISerializationSettings
{
    public CustomerSerializationSettings()
    {
        SerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects,
            ContractResolver = new EntityContractResolver()
                .AddProperties<CustomerModel>(m => m.XXX)
        };

        DeserializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
    }

    public JsonSerializerSettings SerializerSettings { get; private set; }
    public JsonSerializerSettings DeserializerSettings { get; private set; }
}
```

How should I implemented this in .NET Core ? ... and by that I mean the Initialize part in SerializationConfiguration (in .net core: OnActionExecuting in the attribute class)

Answer (score 1):

ActionFilter attribute like that can be used:

```
public class JsonConfigFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext context)
    {
        if (context.Result is ObjectResult objectResult)
        {
            var serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects,
                NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Include,
                ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
            };

            var jsonOutputFormatter = new NewtonsoftJsonOutputFormatter(
                serializerSettings,
                ArrayPool<char>.Shared,
                new MvcOptions
                {
                });

            objectResult.Formatters.Add(jsonOutputFormatter);
        }

        base.OnResultExecuting(context);
    }
}
```

That's for serializing (output).
There is also NewtonsoftJsonInputFormatter for input (former deserializer) if you need it.
This code requires nuget package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson` to be installed.

You can use such attribute on a controller or even on an action method of a controller.